# How can GA is reporting different than GWT

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-search-console

How can it be that GA is reporting 176,722  users as Google organic search, but at the same time, GWT is showing only 1918 clicks and 122,213 impressions for that same week (Jul 19-25)?

When I login to GWT and compare that same week (Jul 19-25) vs. the week prior to launch (May 10-16), I see huge differences in impressions (7,828,324 vs 146,146; a drop of 98% or 53x) and clicks (195,888 vs 2807; down nearly 70x).

Using an independent 3rd-party monitoring service (SeoClarity), we had 16,254 terms ranked in the top 10 on May 16th and 10,465 terms on July 25th, a loss of 35%. The average search volume was a loss of 40% (30,131,780 vs 18,198,740) in potential views.

Is GA over-reporting organic search traffic?
Is GWT under-reporting clicks and impressions?

Comment: Hi Suhail - this channel is for programming help. So, the GA and GTM tags are usually used for assistance with their respective APIs or technical implementation.

Comment: You have to configs and write scripts to get the data and hence it becomes a programming problem

Answer (score 0):

May be wrong tagged paid traffic drops to Google Organic in GA?